# Ngrx store - delay tap after emitting action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Using Ngrx store, I have the following 2 effects:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
    toastSuccess$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(TOAST_SUCCESS),
            map((action: any) => this.toastr.success(action.payload, 'Success'))
        );

@Effect()
    appContextChanged$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(UPDATE_USER_APP_CONTEXT_SUCCESS),
            mergeMap(() => of(
                { type: TOAST_SUCCESS, payload: 'App context updated successfully!' })),
            tap(() => location.reload()),
            catchError(() => of({ type: UPDATE_USER_APP_CONTEXT_FAILED }))
        )
```

What I'd like to do is delay the `tap` `location.reload()` by a 1000ms (so the toast show for a second, then the page is refreshed), but I've tried using `delay` everywhere with no success. How can I delay the refreshing of the page, i.e. `location.reload()` after the toast effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a different effect for that, so`appContextChanged$` can finish and notify your `toastSuccess` effect:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
reload$ = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(TOAST_SUCCESS),
    tap(() => location.reload())
```

It seems `toastr.success` returns an action, is that true? In that case, you can listen to that action instead of `Toast_sucess` in the `ofType` operator.

Comment: That is what this effect is for. I don't agree with what you're suggesting.

Comment: An effect is ued to make a single(!) sideffect. If you don't want to create another effect, put your `delay` and `tap` to the end of `toastSuccess$`. However, I think it 's readable if one effect is only responsible for one thing.

Comment: touché Dániel Barta